# Rails N+1 when referencing to the same model twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, controller

I have 2 models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

end

class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :sender, :class_name => 'User'
  has_one :recipient, :class_name => 'User'
end
```

and I want to get all the messages that a user recieved so in `messages_controller.rb` i have:

```
  def messages_to_user
    messages = Message.where(recipient_id: current_user.id)

    respond_with messages
  end
```

this service works but in the log I can see classic N+1 issue:

```
Started GET "/messages_to_user" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-01-22 15:35:01 +0200
Processing by MessageController#user as */*
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  Message Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "messages".* FROM "messages" WHERE "messages"."recipient_id" = ?  [["recipient_id", 2]]
[active_model_serializers]   User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
[active_model_serializers]   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
[active_model_serializers]   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
[active_model_serializers]   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
[active_model_serializers]   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
[active_model_serializers]   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
[active_model_serializers]   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
[active_model_serializers]   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
[active_model_serializers]   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
[active_model_serializers]   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
[active_model_serializers]   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
[active_model_serializers]   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
[active_model_serializers]   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
[active_model_serializers]   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
[active_model_serializers]   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
[active_model_serializers]   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
[active_model_serializers]   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
[active_model_serializers]   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
[active_model_serializers] Rendered ActiveModel::Serializer::CollectionSerializer with ActiveModelSerializers::Adapter::Attributes (42.01ms)
Completed 200 OK in 217ms (Views: 63.0ms | ActiveRecord: 3.0ms)
```

So I tried to solved it by adding `includes`:

```
  def messages_to_user
    messages = Message.includes(:recipient).where(recipient_id: current_user.id)

    respond_with messages
  end
```

But then I get the following error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: users.message_id: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."message_id" IN ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9')
```

**How it can be fixed?**
I want to return a collection of messages - not a user and a messages set inside the user. but without the N+1 problem

**EDIT**

The connection between the 2 models is done via the messages table, here is the migration (fields sender, recipient), so I dont need the `users.message_id` in `users`. furthermore, any user can send/recieve multiple messages, maybe my implementation does not reflect that? how it should be done?

here is the Messages migration:

```
class CreateMessages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :messasges do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.references :sender, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.references :recipient, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.string :content
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Well, you have to add the required column, the error message is quite clear, there is a missing `message_id` column on the users table.

Comment: @Iceman please see my edit, thatnks.

Comment: I can see that the error message says that this column is missing in users table but sinc user can have many messages I cant put a message_it column there. the right way is to add user_it in the message table, bu then again how can I prevent the n+1?

Comment: It looks like classic has_many :through association, but then I'd expect to have something in User model as well. I assume User should be `sender` or `recepient` or both.

Comment: Both, so I need to add the has_many :through for those fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
messages = Message.includes(:recipient).references(:recipient).where(recipient_id: current_user.id)
```